# Variadic function with recursion

Tags: c++, c++11

I trying to write a recursive function with variadic parameters for copy my data. But this function copy only last parameter. What I do wrong?

This is output:

```
13 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

12 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Best regards.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

void copy_data(unsigned char* ar, unsigned& offset, int data) {
    std::memcpy(ar + offset, (void*)&data, sizeof(data));
    offset += sizeof(data);
}

template<class... Args>
void copy_data(unsigned char* ar, unsigned& offset, int data, Args... args) {
    if ((sizeof...(Args)) == 0) {
        copy_data(ar, offset, data);
    }
    copy_data(ar, offset, args...);
}

void printf_data(const unsigned char* ar, int s) {
    for (int i = 0; i < s; ++i) {
        std::cout << (int)ar[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout<<"\n";
}

int main() {
    unsigned char *arr0 = new unsigned char[16];
    unsigned char *arr1 = new unsigned char[12];

    int p0 = 10;
    int p1 = 11;
    int p2 = 12;
    int p3 = 13;

    unsigned offset = 0;

    copy_data(arr0, offset, p0, p1, p2, p3);

    offset = 0;
    copy_data(arr1, offset, p0, p1, p2);

    printf_data(arr0, 16);
    printf_data(arr1, 12);

    delete [] arr1;
    delete [] arr0;
    return 0;
}
```

UPDATE: corrected function

```
template <typename T>
void copy_data(unsigned char* ar, unsigned& offset, T data) {
    std::memcpy(ar + offset, (void*)&data, sizeof(data));
    offset += sizeof(data);
}

template <typename T, typename... Args>
void copy_data(unsigned char* ar, unsigned& offset, T data, Args... args) {
    copy_data(ar, offset, data);
    copy_data(ar, offset, args...);
}
```

Comment: Note also that your output depends of endianess.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yeees of course! But in this case it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recursion only outputs anything when:

```
if ((sizeof...(Args))==0) {
    copy_data(ar, offset, data);
}
```

and that only happens after you strip every argument except the last off.

Remove the `if` clause.

Comment: Thank you, Adam. It worked

10 0 0 0  11 0 0 0  12 0 0 0  13 0 0 0    \n
10 0 0 0  11 0 0 0  12 0 0 0